# ¿Cómo buscar las palabras de un listado en un documento txt utilizando regex en python?

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un listado de marcas de carros:

`['Nissan','nissan','NISSAN','Chevrolet','chevrolet','CHEVROLET',....n]`

En total son 213, me gustaría usar este listado para buscar la marca del carro en unas facturas que están en formato txt. Lo he intentado con `regex` en python pero no me funciona.

Pongo el listado en un objecto.

```
marcas = ['Nissan','nissan','NISSAN','Chevrolet','chevrolet','CHEVROLET',....n]
```

Abro el archivo:

```
file = open('001_factura.txt').read()
```

Y después intento esto:

```
re.findall(marcas,file)
```

Me aparece este error:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

¿Alguna recomendación?, me ayudarían mucho.
Saludos y Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lee la documentación primero. `findall` requiere un patrón y una cadena; tú le pasas una lista. Enlace: https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/re.html

Comment: sí, lo sé, acepta patrones y cadenas, alguna idea para resolverlo? puede ser de otra forma

Comment: ¿La factura está estructurada o es simplemente un texto?. Si está estructurada, ¿puedes recuperar el campo "carro"? Lo mejor es que edites la pregunta y agregues un ejemplo de archivo de factura, para poder probar la solución.

Comment: Ya lo logré, apliqué un ciclo for, gracias por nada Candid Moe

Comment: Publica tu solución como respuesta para aprender.

Comment: ok, va la solución

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución:

```
#   Todas las marcas conocidas en minúsculas.
marcas = set(['nissan', 'kia', 'hyundai', 'subaru'])

with open("factura.txt", "r") as factura:
    marca = marcas & set(factura.read().lower().split())
    print(marca)
```

Primero, no necesito escribir cada posible forma de cada marca; basta con ponerlas una sola vez en minúsculas.

Segundo, leo todo el archivo separandolo en palabras y colocandolas en minúsculas. Con eso armo un segundo *set*

Luego es cosa de hacer una intersección de conjuntos para encontrar la(s) marca(s) mencionadas en la factura.

**Demo**

factura.txt

```
factura 001
Para nombre
marca Nissan Coupe ZX
precio 1000
```

produce:

```
['Nissan']
```

Incluso funciona con facturas que tengan más de una marca.

factura2.txt

```
factura 002
Para nombre
marca subaru
marca nissan 
precio 2000
```

produce:

```
{'nissan', 'subaru'}
```

Comment: muy buena, gracias por la alternativa

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta

Abro mi archivo:

```
file = open('001_factura.txt').read()
```

Pongo en un objeto la lista:

```
marcas = ['Nissan','nissan','NISSAN','Chevrolet','chevrolet','CHEVROLET',....n]
```

aplico ciclo for utilizando regex:

```
for i in marcas:
    lista = re.findall(i,file)
    if lista != []:
        break
print(lista)
```

Comment: No necesitas expresiones regulares. Basta con hacer `if i in file:` para saber si la marca `i` está en la factura.